# Sending More than 10 emails on salesforce

Tags: email, bulk

Salesforce Developer only allows to send 10 Emails. How can i use the Developer license in Salesforce to send more than 10 emails?

Is there a way to do this? Like coding on Apex or something?  Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

In Developer Edition organizations and organizations evaluating Salesforce during a trial period, your organization can send mass email to no more than 10 external email addresses per day. This lower limit does not apply if your organization was created before the Winter '12 release and already had mass email enabled with a higher limit. Additionally, your organization can send single emails to a maximum of 15 email addresses per day.

The limit is to use sendEmail method 10 times in a day not to send only 10 email/day. To send more then 10 email you need to create a logic which send email to more then one person by using single call of sendEmail  method by adding email it to setToAddresses[] method, setCcAddresses[] ,etc .

Comment: How do I do this? I am quite new to this. Do i have to write a code for this?

Comment: Just pasted what you wrote and something like this https://www.sfdc99.com/2014/03/01/sending-emails-using-apex/ came up. Could this be what you mean?

Comment: Note that emails to User objects, via the setTargetObjectId method on the [message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setTargetObjectId), are not counted in this limit. Thus, if you have users you can use for the email addresses you can send more than 10 emails.

Comment: @PhilWbut i want to know , https://www.sfdc99.com/2014/03/01/sending-emails-using-apex/ can i use to send more than 10 emails

Comment: Yes, you can use it.