# Please advise on How to send More than 10 Emails in Salesforce Developer Account

Tags: email

How do i do this? I am trying to send more than 10 emails on Salesforce developer account. I just have it to send just 10 emails and after that it tells me to send another 10 emails tomorrow. As shown in the image below

[image: 3333333.png]

This can be really tiring. Now i have over 3,000 emails to send. Is there a possibility of creating apex triggers, so that upon uploading the emails into csv once the emails are inserted, it can push emails to the contacts? Please I need some form of clarification here.

Comment: Are you using developer edition?

Comment: If Yes, then you can able to send max 10 emails. Refer [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369225/sending-more-than-10-emails-on-salesforce/369227#369227)

Comment: You appear to be trying to circumvent a dev org limit without purchasing Salesforce licenses. I think you will find you simply need to buy licenses and a production org to allow you to implement your requirements appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an SF license to send more emails in one day. as you can send only 10 emails per day.